# React - appendChild() a React Link tag to existing li appends [object, object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, append, html-lists

Have a loop that qualifies if an objects date key/value matches a date on a calendar.  If it does I want it to append a React Link tag to the corresponding li element.  The condition loop works fine, but when it appends the Link tag it is appending [object, object] since I am using createTextNode().

Is there another way to append a Link tag to an existing li without using createTextNode()?

I am done the usual google search with no luck.

```
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
     const link = (<Link to={`/events/${events[i].eventId}`}> . 
                  {events[i].title}</Link>);
     const eventLink = document.createTextNode(link);

     if (events[i].date.slice(15) === day.toString()) {
     cell.appendChild(eventLink);
    }
}
```

Need the li element to contain the React Link tag and not a text node.

UPDATE
Code with ReactDOM render and BrowserRouter but when I click the Link tag React doesn't render the route component.

```
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    const link = (
                <>
        {day.toString()}
        <Link to={`/events/${events[i].eventId}`}>{events[i].title}</Link>
        </>);

        const eventDate = events[i].date.split('-');
        const eventYear = eventDate[0];
        const eventMonth = eventDate[1];
        const eventDay = eventDate[2];
        if (eventDay === day.toString() &&
        eventMonth === (month + 1).toString() &&
        eventYear === year.toString()) {
        ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter>{link}</BrowserRouter>, cell);
            }
        }
```

Comment: clarification: I know how to add a HTML anchor tag.  I am looking to add the React Link tag.  It may not make a huge difference but in the sprit of consistency it would be nice.

Comment: The `Link` tag from `react-router` is not simply a wrapper around anchor tags it works with the router context , not just pushing a new url to your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you need to do it this way - I'm pretty sure there are other ways to render `Link`s based on an array into your DOM.

However if you insist, you should use `ReactDOM`

In your loop:

```
// create an empty div to hold our links:
const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');

// render links into the empty div
ReactDOM.render(eventLinks, tempDiv);

// append the link, since you don't want the div in cell
cell.appendChild(tempDiv.firstChild); // there is only 1 child
```

This is very "hacky" - I'd highly recommend looking for a real "React" way of doing this.

---

EDIT:

your updated code won't work. `react-router` relies on an internal context to navigate, and the `*Router` components provide that context - your code renders a `BrowserRouter` for each link meaning each link will has its own context. Multiple routers probably won't work well in one page as they will fight control over the browser.

First of all you probably shouldn't call `ReactDOM.render` in each iteration of your loop. `ReactDOM.render` takes control of all the content inside your `cell` - rendering it again and again meaning only the last call works.

Secondly, your `BrowserRouter` should be placed at the top level of your App (e.g. in your root component).

Again, manipulating dom like that is not how you should use React. I'm curious what kind of app you are building and how it is structured?

---

So here's what I think you should do - since you are already using react, I imagine there is a component tree (e.g. you have a top level component that renders other components, etc.)

So at the very top of your app, you should wrap everything in the BrowserRouter.

```
// index.js, maybe.

// assuming App is your "top level component"
import App from './App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'))
```

And, now, create a `EventLinks` component that renders all the links:

```
// EventLinks.jsx

const EventLinks = ({ events }) => (
  events.map((event) => (
    <li key={event.eventId}>
      <Link to={`/events/${event.eventId}`}>
        {event.title}
      </Link>
    </li>
  ))
);
```

In your component where `cell` lives, render the links directly.

```
// Cell component

const Cell = ({ events }) => {
  // filter events if you need to here, since you have that `if` logic originally

  const visibleEvents = events.filter(filterFunction);

  return (
    <ul>
      <EventLinks events={visibleEvents} />
    </ul>
  );
}
```

This is probably not exactly match your app's structure but I hope you get the idea.

so your `App` renders a layout and `Cell` component, and then your `Cell` renders `EventLinks`.

Honestly you shouldn't be using ReactDOM at all except for the only entry point of your app.

Comment: Thanks Yurui.  Still pretty fresh to React so working on my 'hackiness' still ;)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes my <App /> component is wrapped in the <BrowserRouter>.  All of my other paths render as they should.  I think the issue with this is the component that this function lives in is being called by one of those Routes.  
Structure is this:
BrowserRouter > App > Router > Events(This calls the Calendar Component which is where this function lives and filters thru a database of events to match them to the corresponding date)

Good to know about the ReactDOM only using the last render call.  That won't work then as there maybe more than one event per day.

Comment: What you should do is render the Links directly with React (as a component)

Comment: Updated my answer again to include an example of what you should do instead.

Comment: Thanks Yurui.  This makes sense.  Will give a try now and let you know.

Comment: So this doesn't work either. Must be the structure I have but I don't see it.  The entire App component is wrapped in the <BrowserRouter> and the App calls a <Router /> which holds a <Switch> to all the <Route />'s.  I have tried your suggestion and a few others but all result in <Link> outside <Router>

Comment: Also the suggestion you gave would only render the days with events.  What I am trying to accomplish is inserting a Link tag into a calendar if that event is on that specific day.  here is a link to my repo if you find the time to see where I went wrong.  I am somewhat new to React so please forgive any naive building habits.
[https://github.com/ryancarville/bequia-forum-app](https://github.com/ryancarville/bequia-forum-app)

Comment: You dont need `Router` in `App` if `App` is already wrapped in `BrowserRouter`

Comment: I checked your repo - so the root cause is that you are not really using `react` to render the calendar & events. I see you are trying to use `ReactDOM.hydrate` to render the links which won't work - like I mentioned earlier you shouldn't need `ReactDOM` inside your app. `dyrate` is the same as `render` except its for SSR. When you render links that way, they are not seeing the context in your react app (react is rendering them thinking they are smaller independent apps. Also you are try to manipulate the DOM with DOM API which is usually a no-no for react apps.

Comment: Opened a PR on your repo @RyanCarville

Comment: You are awesome!  Just looked at your pull.  Beyond grateful!  I will have the time to implement it tomorrow and will let you know how it goes.  Again that you so much for your generosity!

Comment: This did it!  I just have to add a toSting() to the qualifiers.  I am guessing it was all because of the nested functions.  Breaking them apart allowed React to have a more clear 'line of sight' for the router.  Thank you again!

Comment: Great - you are very welcome :D The key is stop manipulating the DOM directly - let React handle all the renders. Also try to avoid using `ReactDOM` - React can't "see" what you are changing in the DOM, when you use `ReactDOM.render` the rendered stuff is outside of your app's context thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

if i am getting your questions correctly you are trying to add to a li element a link(of React link) as the text inside the li element(and if im correct as clickable link ..... anchor tag element)

cell must be the correct li element in which i assume you iterate parallel to the event, then here is a possible solution:

```
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
     const link = (<Link to={`/events/${events[i].eventId}`}> . 
                  {events[i].title}</Link>);

     if (events[i].date.slice(15) === day.toString()) {
     let tempComponent = ReactDOM.createElement("li",{...propertiesIfNeeded},link)
     ReactDOM.render(tempComponent,cell) //you could also pass here refrece to cell/li items where i wrote cell(eg.document.querySelect....)
    }
}
```

or solution 2 creating the li as part of the link component you create in the iteration:

```
for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
         const link = (<li><Link to={`/events/${events[i].eventId}`}> . 
                      {events[i].title}</Link></li>);

         if (events[i].date.slice(15) === day.toString()) {
         ReactDOM.render(link,cell) //you could also pass here refrece to cell/li items where i wrote cell(eg.document.querySelect....)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `ReactDOM.render(link,cell) ` is going to replace everything in `cell` with that `link` I think your code will end up with rendering only the last child ?

Comment: well, that's true. 
but the assumption is that the li element is empty and ready to be overwritten with the new element and if not then it can be easily fixed appending to the li element a placeholder element.

Comment: thanks all!  The li element already has text content of a number which represents the date on the calendar.  So I can't empty the existing li but only append to it. (unless i take extra steps to copy the current text and insert total new content)

But I think the ```ReactDOM``` approach is the answer.  Will try it out shortly and give you an update.

Comment: So the ReactDOM.render could work but hitting a "<Link> outside <Router>" error.  The component has withRouter attached.  Thanks again in advance.  New to React so the help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: OK So I got the compiler to run everything as it should.  Link tag in and in the right cell.  But when I click the Link tag the path changes but React doesn't render the route component

Comment: are you using react-router?

Comment: Italy Wolfish, I am.

Comment: @RyanCarville have you registered your components to the right routes(the routes you are trying to hop into with the links)
and React Routes with variables(aka url params)
[React Router: Declerative Routing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: @ItalyWolfish I have.  And have.  The Events component is render when a path is hit and that Events component calls the Calendar component that is trying to make these Links.